# Spotlight index only specified folder

Tags: spotlight

I have found ways to disable spotlight indexing for a specific folder. But, how do I do the reverse. I want to

1. disable all indexing
2. enable for just one or two folder I specify.

is it possible? How.

Also any side effect, like slowing down some system operation (other than search results)